# Avoiding code duplication when writing fluent-style API using interfaces

Tags: c#, fluent, c#-9.0

I'm trying to write a fluid API for building entities in my C# program.

I have a base entity that has some properties plus a collection of polymorphic entities: They all descend from a common base type but some will have additional properties.

Here is an example:

```
public interface IGarageBuilder
{
  public IGarageBuilder Label(string label);
  public IGarageBuilder AddCar(Action<ICarBuilder> configure);
  public IGarageBuilder AddBike(Action<IBikeBuilder > configure);
}

public interface IVehicleBuilder
{
  public IVehicleBuilder Model(string model); // <- That is the member that is causing me trouble
}

public interface IBikeBuilder : IVehicleBuilder
{
  
}

public interface ICarBuilder : IVehicleBuilder
{
  public ICarBuiler HorsePoser(int horsePower);
}
```

(The software I write has a lot of properties common to all IVehicleBuilder, I simplified this a lot).

I'm having an issue with the IVehicleBuilder interface: defined like above, the folowing code will not compile:

```
public void BuildGarage(IGarageBuilder builder)
{
  builder.Label("My dream garage")
    .AddCar(opt => opt.Model("Ford").HorsePower(120)); // <- this fails because .Model() returns a IVehicleBuilder interface, not an ICarBuilder 
}
```

Now, I could do without the dependancy between IVehicleBuilder and ICarBuilder and copy the "Model()" API to both ICarBuilder and IBikeBuilder but, in my real app, I have dozens of such API, several of which are override for allowing different ways to configure the entity. Furthermore, I would have to copy the implementations as well since they now return different types.

Is there a way to avoid all that code duplication?

Comment: You could make `IVehicleBuilder` generic, would that be an option?

Comment: Shouldn't `AddCar` return a type of `ICarBuilder` and not `IGarageBuilder`?

Comment: You are building a car, but not specifying that you are building a car, you need a way to either drop down to a more specific type (i.e. make `IVehicleBuilder` return a car/bike) or start with a more specific type early on.

Comment: @Matin No, AddCar takes a delegate that will take the builder as parameter and returns the IGarageBuilder back (so new vehicles can be added)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to reducing duplication is to split your interfaces into two levels. One level describes the different sorts of methods (or groups of methods) available, and the higher level groups those together into the fluent interfaces used by the API, using interface inheritance:

```cs
public interface IHasModel<T>
{
    T Model(string model);
}

public interface ICarBuilder : IHasModel<ICarBuilder>
{
    // Things which are specific to just cars can go in here if you want, rather than
    // taking up a separate IHasHorsePower<T>
    ICarBuilder HorsePower(int horsePower);
}

public interface IBikeBuilder : IHasModel<IBikeBuilder> { }
```

Additionally, try to keep the same underlying builder implementation for all interfaces. This can have methods and bits of states which will only be used by a single builder, and that's fine.

```cs
internal class Builder : ICarBuilder, IBikeBuilder
{
    // May or may not be used, depending on what we're building...
    private string model;
    private int horsePower;
    
    public Builder Model(string model)
    {
        this.model = model;
        return this;
    }
    
    // Annoyingly return type covariance isn't yet supported for implicit interface
    // implementations, so we need this boilerplate
    ICarBuilder IHasModel<ICarBuilder>.Model(string model) => Model(model);
    IBikeBuilder IHasModel<IBikeBuilder>.Model(string model) => Model(model);
    
    // You can avoid the song-and-dance for simple things, which are just referenced
    // by a single interface
    public ICarBuilder HorsePower(int horsePower)
    {
        this.horsePower = horsePower;
        return this;
    }

    // I assume you'll have something like this as well...
    public Car BuildCar() => new Car(model, horsePower);
    public Bike BuildBike() => new Bike(model);
}
```

Comment: Downside of this is if you have 20 types of vehicle, the builder now needs to implement 20 interfaces.

Comment: It's true, but it's easier than having 20 builder classes, each implementing 1 interface

Comment: But in this case, OP *is* building multiple things so it makes sense to have multiple builders. Sure, have an abstract base builder object to keep shared code, but then specialise into individual builders.

Comment: Those things they're building have a lot in common though: both bikes and cars have a model, for instance. Having separate car/bike builders means duplicating that logic across two builders, whereas having one builder which can build both cars and bikes reduces that boilerplate. This is my experience from writing fluent interfaces, anyway.

Comment: Sure, but the moment you put car stuff into the generic builder class you have polluted your code. For me, keeping them in separate classes is important.

Comment: Sure, but OP is asking how to *reduce* the code duplication. I've tried to answer that. They can decide whether they like the smell or not :) Think of the builder as a vehicle builder which can build any type of vehicle, rather than a merged car/bike builder.

Comment: But there won't be code duplication if you keep the common bits in a base class.

Comment: That works right up to the point where you have an intersection of functionality (maybe cars and bikes have wheels, but dogsleds and cars have space for a dog, and there's no way to structure that as a linear chain of inheritance), and you realise that C# doesn't support multiple inheritance.